# Unable to find local files when using FTP

Tags: command-line, batch, ftp

I'm trying to create a plain FTP file and a batch file for my colleagues to use to upload som zipped files to a database.

The problem I run into is, when connected to the server, I cannot reach my local files I want to upload.

For example:

```
C:\Users\310176421>ftp
ftp> open site.company.com
Connected to site.company.com.
220 (vsFTPd 2.2.2)
User (site.company.com:(none)): 310104156
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
230 Login successful.
ftp> mput "test.txt"
test.txt:File not found
ftp> bye
221 Goodbye.
```

Thank you!

Comment: If you type `mdir` to get a local directory listing, does test.txt appear?

Comment: @Narzard the output of mdir is empty. Edit - This only lists the remote directory. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490663.aspx

Comment: That is the issue. Your local working directory seems to be incorrect. Where is the test.txt file stored on your local machine? Try adding in a `lcd "C:\users\test\` or wherever the folder is that test.txt is in, then do an `mput test.txt`

Comment: I simply entered `lcd` in the ftp shell, and it was the correct folder, however it still cannot find the file.

Comment: Let see a new ftp session output using the `LS` and `DIR` commands.